# jQuery DateTimePicker add 5 minutes to current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I use a jQuery DateTime picker and i want to set the time when the DateTime picker open to the current date +5 minutes.
Example: If I open the DateTime picker at 12:00 , the time bar should let me pick max 12:05. Is this possible?

```
    $( ".DateTimePickerTodayAudit" ).datetimepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showCurrentAtPos: 0,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      maxDate: 0,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to this: I've created a javaScript function that returns the current date +5 minutes and assigned the maxDate property of the DateTimePicker with the functions returned value.

```
     function currDate()
    {
    var d = new Date();
    var y = d.getFullYear();
    var m = d.getMonth() ;
    var da = d.getDate();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var mi = d.getMinutes()+5;
    var se = d.getSeconds();
    var mDate = new Date(y, m, da, h, mi,se);
    return mDate;

    };

$( ".DateTimePickerTodayAudit" ).datetimepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showCurrentAtPos: 0,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        maxDate:currDate(),
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various possibilities depending on your case scenario but. One way this could be handled is by providing an array of time.

[examples retrieved from datetimepicker docs](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

**allowTimes options TimePicker Example #**

**javaScript**

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
 datepicker:false,
 allowTimes:[
  '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', 
  '17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
 ]
});
```

there is also a min and max possibility. Altough the below example is with minTime.

**Set options runtime DateTimePicker #**

If select day is Saturday, the minimum set 11:00, otherwise 8:00

**javaScript**

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
  // 'this' is jquery object datetimepicker
  if( currentDateTime.getDay()==6 ){
    this.setOptions({
      minTime:'11:00'
    });
  }else
    this.setOptions({
      minTime:'8:00'
    });
};
jQuery('#datetimepicker_rantime').datetimepicker({
  onChangeDateTime:logic,
  onShow:logic
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your idea with the function really helped.

Comment: @Cosmin glad to be of service , please accept the answer when possible.